# image with link in first of video - jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, video-player

I want when user click on play , First see an image with link , then video play for him , How i can do that ?

like this link : [aparat](http://www.aparat.com/v/wBM3h)

my code

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: 'video.mp4',
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    title: 'Basic Video Embed',
    description: 'A video with a basic title and description!',
    primary: 'html5'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Click to play is the default behavior of your player.You can add an image file as part of your setup. If you want to add autoplay (the opposite of what you describe above, simply add "autostart: true,"

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
      file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
      image: "/uploads/myImage.jpg",
      width: 640,
      height: 270,
      mute: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: probably this link will help : https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407439-adding-preview-thumbnails